# How do I get the file name only, assign it to a variable and use later?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim myStream As Stream
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    Dim saveFileName As String = ""
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = saveFileName
        Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(myStream)
            ' Add some text to the file.
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - " + saveFileName) ' Date and File title header
            sw.WriteLine("-------------------")
            ' Arbitrary objects can also be written to the file.
            sw.Write("The date is: ")
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now)
            sw.Close()
        End Using

        If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
            ' Code to write the stream goes here.
            myStream.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The variable is saveFileName, however when I use the saveFileDialog1.FileName as it, it is empty or provides the full path to the file, how do I only get the name? (such as test.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

```
 saveFileName = Path.GetFileName(saveFileDialog1.FileName)
```

Comment: This worked, after changing Path.GetDirectoryName() to Path.GetFileName(), thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 DIM fileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(SavefileDialog.FileName)
```